# Best way to create a repository for exams

Tags: exam, teaching

I'm a teacher of an elementary school and I'm using \LaTeX through [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com)(w/ [exam class](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf)) in order to create my exams. After almost one year of work, I have a lot of exams in my folders and I would like to organize it better.

The point is that I would like to know the best way to create a repository for my questions because I need, all the time, make new exams and I just make small changes on my old questions. I would like to have a way to easily use this questions simply typing an ID of the question. Is it possible? Do you have any suggestions in how to do it?

Comment: maybe have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank?lang=en

Comment: Welcome! What class do you use for your exams, article? Do you need any particular packages? I use `article` with [`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim). That allows some modularity thanks to the tags, but I still create a new document every time a new semester starts. If you are know a bit about command-line interfaces (terminal, console), maybe some scripting could help you?

Comment: Does your editor have a multifile search?

Comment: What I do is to split the questions in separate files and then `\input` them into the exam. I also put the solutions in separate files because I like the solutions printed after the questions.